# How to register C++ nested class to Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I am currently able to bind C++ classes to Lua, wrapped up in modules that I load using `luaL_requiref` with proper static open functions that does the `luaL_newmetatable`, `luaL_setfuncs`, etc. handling. Works great.

But what if I wanted to bind a nested class?

Consider the following C++ code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(){}
    void do_something();

    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar(){}
        void do_something_else();
    };
};
```

And the Lua registration:

```
int foo_new(lua_State* L) {
    new(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(foo)))foo();
    luaL_setmetatable(L, "Foo");
    return 1;
}
int foo_do_something(lua_State* L) {
    Foo* foo = (Foo*)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Foo");
    foo->do_something();
    return 0;
}
int luaopen_foo(lua_State* L) {
    const luaL_Reg functions[] = {
        {"__index", foo_new},
        {"do_something", foo_do_something},
        {nullptr, nullptr}
    };
    if( luaL_newmetatable(L, "Foo") ) {
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    }
    return 1;
}

...

luaL_requiref(L, "Foo", luaopen_foo, 1);
```

I can access `Foo::do_something()` in Lua as such:

```
foo = Foo()
foo:do_something()
```

**Now the question:** How do I register the `Foo::Bar` nested class in Lua so that I can access it as such:

```
bar = Foo.Bar()
bar:do_something_else()
```

Essentially, I want to register the `Bar` methods in the `Foo` metatable rather than globally. Do I require another call to `luaL_requiref` or can I do it in a single `luaL_requiref`?

Thank you!

Comment: You've become the victim of several generations' worth of sloppy terminology. While `Bar` looks a bit "sub", it isn't a *subclass* at all. It is a *nested* class. We prefer the technical terms "base class", "derived class" and "member type", which aren't so easy to misunderstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: OK, now it's a whole different question.

Yes, you can do it in a single call.

The `luaL_requiref` function simply calls the passed function with bells and whistles, such as checking if the module's not loaded yet (and updating the `package.loaded` table), registering the corresponding global value, etc.

I assume you don't want to ever load `Bar` separately from `Foo` or `Foo` without `Bar`, therefore a single `"Foo"` entry in `package.loaded` should suffice. Likewise, there is no need in a global `Bar` variable.

So, simply put it as a field of your `Foo`, and that's it.

P.S. Make sure you ever get your destructors called: Typically if you use `lua_newuserdata` with placement new, you need to use the `__gc` metamethod.

EDIT2: Modify your luaopen_Foo method (note `__call`, not `__index` for the constructors. Personally I prefer `new` for this purpose, but if you want to create them as `local f = Foo()`, then you need `__call`):

```
int luaopen_foo(lua_State* L) 
{
    static const luaL_Reg functions[] = 
    {
        {"__call"       , foo_new},
        {"do_something" , foo_do_something},
        {nullptr        , nullptr}
    };

    if (luaL_newmetatable(L, "Foo")) 
    {
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

        // =================
        // Here, your "Foo" metatable is on top of your stack
        // about to be returned as the result of your luaopen_Foo.
        // Simply put another table above and set if as a Foo.Bar
        if (luaopen_FooBar(L))
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "Bar");
    }
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_FooBar(lua_State * L)
{
    static const luaL_Reg functions[] = 
    {
        {"__call"            , foo_bar_new},
        {"do_something_else" , foo_bar_do_something_else},
        {nullptr             , nullptr}
    };

    // luaL_newmetatable puts its result on top of the stack
    // - exactly what we want for lua_setfield
    if (luaL_newmetatable(L, "Foo::Bar"))
    {
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    }
    return 1; // Indicate the result is on top of the stack
}
```

If you were ever curious, what does the luaL_requiref function (with some pseudo-code):

```
void luaL_requiref(lua_State *L, const char *name, lua_CFunction openf, int set_global) 
{
    if (!try_get_already_loaded_module(modname))
    {
        lua_pushcfunction(L, openf); // Call the openf function
        lua_pushstring(L, modname);  // with modname as its argument
        lua_call(L, 1, 1);

        memorize_the_result_for_future(modname);
    }
    if (set_global)
    {
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);       // copy the module
        lua_setglobal(L, modname);  // set _G[modname] = module
    }
}
```

Note the difference: `luaL_requiref` calls your function from within Lua, which ensures proper stack cleanup after its execution, e.g. you can put some garbage there, the only thing you have to make sure is that your top-level value is what you want to result along with `return 1;`. You don't have that luxury if you call that function directly, though. So make sure it *only adds a single value on top of the stack*.

Comment: Ok I admit I wrote this pretty quickly - I removed the `static` keywords. The question isn't about the usefulness of instanciating a _class_ in Lua. It is specifically about using `luaL_requiref` to register the _class_.

Comment: Edited. Do you need it more detailed?

Comment: I do setup global destructor, etc., just wanted to abbreviate the code. Now, which functions do I need to call to register `Bar` as a field like you said? I can't get it working for some reason.

Comment: Updated. Is it any better for you now?

Comment: Thanks that clarified where my issue was! It works like a charm now!